# Python Algebra Fractions

Tags: python, algebra, fractions

I hate to admit it but this little line of code is giving me some troubles.

```
print 15 + (-1*(((yearnum + yearnum / 4 - yearnum / 100 + yearnum / 400) + 11) % 7)) % 7
```

Why is this not equivalent to?

```
print 15 + (-1*(((497 * yearnum / 400) + 11) % 7)) % 7
```

Maybe I have completely forgotten how fractions work?

Comment: Can you perhaps add the steps as to how you go to the incorrect simplification?  It's probably order of operations, or a miscalculated fraction.  Seeing the steps, it will be easier to spot than simplifying from the beginning (read: I'm lazy :p).

Comment: `yearnum (1+1/4-1/100+1/400)` is correctly simplified to `yearnum (497/400)` where the mathematics is concerned - i think

Comment: The function of the division operator was hotly contested. For backwards compatibility, all 2.x Pythons do integer division with `/`, but you can use [`from __future__ import division`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/) to tell them not to. It's best practice to use `//` explicitly if you want the integer division, since that always does the expected thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(yearnum + yearnum / 4 - yearnum / 100 + yearnum / 400)` does not equal `(497 * yearnum / 400) + 11) % 7)` as a result of integer division (Python floors the result of integer division).

Comment: Talk about forgetting the basics. You are 100% correct. Thanks for pointing this out. And with that I call it quits for the day.

Comment: You can avoid this problem by putting decimal points after every number, thus forcing python to use floats instead of integers. 1/4=0, but 1./4.=0.25